# Can't update a single-select field of an issue in jira with Java Jira Rest Cllient

Tags: java, spring, jira

I'm trying to update a single-select field to a null (not selected).

The thing is that when I'm updating the issue to get a selected value it works perfectly and when I'm creating the issue with this field to null also works perfectly.

I'm using a Map where I'm setting the values to the ones I pass from a json and then I'm trying to do the update like this (I'm just writing the one that don't works, the rest works perfectly):

```
map.put("publishable", new FieldInput("customfield_10318", null));

IssueInput newValues = new IssueInput(map, null);
issueClient.updateIssue(issueKey, newValues).claim();
```

Is like when I do the update don't let me to put the new value of the field to null.

How can i make to update the value of the field to null?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you (should) know, the single-select field save the datas as an array, so when you set the field to null it won't work, the thing you should use is the `Collections.emptySet()`, this must work